# "I like better the red hat" or "I like the red hat better?"

Tags: word-order

I've only seen "like better" with the object in between but is it correct to use the object after?

In other words:

**I like this one better.**

or

**I like better this one.**

Is only the first one proper/correct?

Comment: Other than something like "Which do you like better: the red one or the blue one?" where have you seen "like better" used in this way?  It's not natural English.

Comment: @Andrew - I think the question says that the OP **hasn't** seen this version, but simply wants to know if it can be used.

Comment: In a textbook. "I like this one better. I like the blue one better." I wonder if I can upload a picture here.

Comment: @ J.R. Yes, I haven't seen "I like better this one."

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/234833/i-like-that-one-better

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second sentence is not natural English.  Ordinarily the only place you would see "like better" is in a question such as:

> Which do you **like better**?  The red one or the blue one.

Answer:

> I **like** the red one **better**.